# How to move a div smoothly from one constant point to the position of the button that was clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I'm making a battleship game and I want every time you click the "trebuchet" gif to appear, a fireball to appear and then the fireball to move from a set point on top of the trebuchet gif to the position of the button that was clicked.

It won't let me upload a 3mb gif, so here you can see what i'm doing

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ma85W.jpg

plain javascript and plain css, I don't know jquery or sass yet

this is the function that it's activated every time a button is clicked

```
function disparo(casilla)
{
    casilla.style.backgroundImage= "none" ;
    trebuchetS.play();
    document.getElementById("trebuchet").style.display="block";
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById("trebuchet").style.display="none";
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById("fireball").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("fireball").style.display="block"
    }, 500);
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById("fireball").style.display="none";
    }, 3000);
}
```

I know this sounds lazy, but so far I haven't tried any kind of animation because I don't even know what to do for that.
Sorry, I'm very new on CSS and web design in general

Comment: We'dneed to see your CSS for moving the fireball, but just changing its display setting to block then to none isn't going to change its position so you'll need some JS to decide where you want it to move from/to.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own?

Answer (score 0):

see it working
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSqdf.jpg
solved it with this

```
function disparo(casilla)
{
    casilla.style.backgroundImage= "none" ;
    trebuchetS.play();
    let objetivo=casilla.getBoundingClientRect();
    casillaTop=objetivo.top;
    casillaLeft=objetivo.left;
    document.getElementById("trebuchet").style.display="block";
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById("trebuchet").style.display="none";
    }, 1000);
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById("fireball").style.display="block";
        document.getElementById("fireball").animate([
            // keyframes
  {left: `${casillaLeft}px`, top: `${casillaTop}px`}
             ],{
  // timing options
  duration: 1500,
});
    }, 500);
    setTimeout(() => {
        document.getElementById("fireball").style.display="none";
    }, 2000);
}
```